# Method that returns (one, but can be different type) Array?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So i have gotten the task of converting a Microsoft App to IOS and I've stumbled upon a little issue that works in C# but not in swift 2.

What i want to do, is what the title says and heres the code.

```
private let secondsCircle = CAShapeLayer()
private let minutesCircle = CAShapeLayer()
private let hoursCircle = CAShapeLayer()
private var shapeLayers: [CAShapeLayer] = []


private let secondsGradientMask = CAGradientLayer()
private let minutesGradientMask = CAGradientLayer()
private let hoursGradientMask = CAGradientLayer()
private var gradientLayers: [CAGradientLayer] = []
```

The 2 different types i want to return, according to the right TYPE of array, is CAShapeLayer and CAGradientLayer. My Method that checks and "sorts" it out is here:

```
 private func iterateThroughCollection(collection: Array<AnyObject>) -> Array<AnyObject> {
    let newCollection: Array<AnyObject> = collection

    if var getLayer = newCollection as? Array<CAShapeLayer> where getLayer.count == 0 {
        getLayer.append(self.secondsCircle)
        getLayer.append(self.minutesCircle)
        getLayer.append(self.hoursCircle)
        return getLayer
    } else if var getGradients = newCollection as? Array<CAGradientLayer> where getGradients.count == 0 {
        getGradients.append(self.secondsGradientMask)
        getGradients.append(self.minutesGradientMask)
        getGradients.append(self.hoursGradientMask)
        return getGradients 
    }
    return newCollection
}
```

The issue i have is when it returns the new Array it doesn't let me iterate through the different Elements:
[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii6B9.png)
And i really don't know why? I have the exact same thing working in C#. And i can't see why this shouldn't work

*(Note: I have tried with [] instead of Array<>.
 tried to return only 1 specific type with success but not with the second option)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Arrays
An array stores values of the same type in an ordered list. The same value can appear in an array multiple times at different positions.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1 Prerelease).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l

In Swift the elements of an array must be of the same type. However if you use an NSArray or NSMutableArray from the Apple API, then you can store different types within the same collection.
re: NSArray documentation:

"The array representation in the file identified by aPath must contain only property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects). For more details, see Property List Programming Guide. The objects contained by this array are immutable, even if the array is mutable."

After loading the array correctly you can loop through it in Swift using loops or functions like `map`, etc.